# closed convex hull, closure of convex hull and convex hull of closure

Tags: topological-vector-spaces, convex-hulls

Let $X$ a topological vector space and $A\subseteq X$ a subspace. Let $co(A)$ the *convex hull of $A$* (the smallest convex subspace containing $A$)  and $\overline{co}(A)$ the *closed convex hull of $A$* (the smallest closed and convex subspace containing $A$).
What is the relationship between $\overline{co}(A)$, $\overline{co(A)}$ and $co(\bar{A})$? Are they always equal?

In a related question
[closure, convex hull and closed convex hull](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/229781/closure-convex-hull-and-closed-convex-hull) they found different counterexamples, but in the book "Topological Vector Spaces" by Lawrence Narici and Edward Beckenstein they give a proof of the fact that they are all equal:

[image]